# Factor of a product ring can not be free

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, free-modules

I have seen the following property in my class note but I don´t know how to prove, could someone help me?

If we consider the product ring $R=R_1\times{}R_2$, then $R_1$ can not be a free right $R$-module

I think that it must have a simple proof, but I don't get it.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want a proof that this is *always* the case, or simply that $R_1$ need not be a free $R$-module? If it is the latter, then a cardinality argument would work: suppose $R_1\cong\Bbb{F}_2$ and $R_2\cong\Bbb{F}_3.$ In this case, $\# R = 6.$ As any [finite] free $R$-module $M$ satisfies $M\cong \bigoplus_{i = 1}^n R$ for some $n,$ we have $\# M = 6^n.$ But $2\neq 6^n$ for any integer $n.$

Comment: Yes, I want to prove that in every  product ring $R=R_1\times R_2$ (with $R_1$ and $R_2$ non trivial) we have that $R_1$ is not free

Answer (score 1):

Let $F$ be a nonzero free left $R$-module. Then $\operatorname{Ann}_R(F)=\{r\in R:rF=0\}=\{0\}$.

This is essentially obvious, because $F$ is a direct sum of copies of $R$.

Now note that, when $R=R_1\times R_2$, $\operatorname{Ann}_R(R_1\times\{0\})=\{0\}\times R_2$. If neither $R_1$ nor $R_2$ is the trivial ring, we're done.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that things are non-trivial, that is, both $R_1$ and $R_2$ are not the zero ring.

Now, multiplication in the product ring $R_1 \times R_2$ is coordinate-wise, that is, for an element $(a_1, a_2) \in R_1 \times R_2$ with $a_1 \in R_1$ and $a_2 \in R_2$, and another element $(b_1, b_2) \in R_1 \times R_2$ with $b_1 \in R_1$ and $b_2 \in R_2$, we have
$$
(a_1, a_2) \cdot (b_1, b_2) = (a_1 \cdot a_2, b_1 \cdot b_2).
$$

Moreover, we can identify the ring $R_1$ with the subring $R_1 \times \{0_{R_2}\} \subseteq R_1 \times R_2$ where $0_{R_2}$ denotes the zero element of $R_2$. The identification map is
$$
\iota_1 : R_1 \rightarrow R_1 \times R_2,\quad a \mapsto (a, 0_{R_2}).
$$
Now, $R_1 \times \{0_{R_2}\}$, being a subring of $R_1 \times R_2$, is a right $(R_1 \times R_2)$-module, where the module operation is given by ring multiplication. That is, if we have a "module element" $(a_1, 0_{R_2}) \in R_1 \times \{0_{R_2}\}$ and a "coefficiont ring element" $(a_2, b_2) \in R_1 \times R_2$, then the product is
$$
(a_1, 0_{R_2}) \cdot (a_2, b_2) = (a_1 \cdot a_2, 0_{R_2}).
$$
Now, since both $R_1$ and $R_2$ are not the zero ring, we can pick $a_3 \in R_1 \setminus \{0_{R_1}\}$ and $b_3 \in R_2 \setminus \{0_{R_2}\}$. With these, we construct a nonzero "module element" $(a_3, 0_{R_2}) \in R_1 \times \{0_{R_2}\}$ and a nonzero "coefficient ring element" $(0_{R_1}, b_3) \in \in R_1 \times R_2$. Their product is then
$$
(a_3, 0_{R_2}) \cdot (0_{R_1}, b_3) = (0_{R_1}, 0_{R_2}).
$$
That is, the product of a nonzero module element and a nonzero coefficient ring element is the zero module element.
This does not happen in a free module.

So we have shown that $R_1 \times \{0_{R_2}\}$ is not a free right $(R_1 \times R_2)$-module.

Comment: Suppose $R = \Bbb{C}[x]/(x^2).$ Then $M = R$ is certainly a free $R$-module, and $x\in R$ is a nonzero ring (and module) element. However, $x\cdot x = 0$ in $R.$ You need to ensure that the elements you choose are not only nonzero, but non-zero divisors (and of course, elements of the form $(0,r)$ and $(r,0)$ are always zero divisors in a product ring).

Comment: Another counterexample to the claim that "the product of a nonzero module element and a nonzero coefficient ring element is never the zero module element in a free module" is the following: let $R$ be a nonzero ring, and consider the free rank one $R\times R$-module $M = R\times R.$ Then $(1,0)\cdot(0,1) = (0,0),$ but $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ are nonzero ring/module elements.

Comment: So, is not this proof right?

Comment: @mejopa no, this argument is incorrect - the same logic would imply that $R_1\times R_2$ is not free over itself, which is absurd.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $R_1$ and $R_2$ are nontrivial, and consider $R_1 = M$ as a right $R = R_1\times R_2$-module via the natural action
\begin{align*}
M\times R&\to M\\
(m,(r,s))&\mapsto mr.
\end{align*}

To show that $M$ is not free over $R,$ we must show that there is no basis of $M.$ Recall that a basis of $M$ is a subset $B = \{e_i\mid i\in I\}\subseteq M$ such that the following two conditions hold:

1. For any $m\in M,$ there exists a finite subset $J\subseteq I$ and collection of elements $\{r_j\mid j\in J\}\subseteq R$ such that $$m = \sum_{j\in J} e_j r_j,$$ and
2. If $\{r_j\mid j\in J\subseteq I\}\subseteq R$ is a finite collection of elements of $R$ such that $$\sum_{j\in J} e_j r_j = 0,$$ then $r_j = 0$ for all $j.$

To that end, suppose such a basis $B = \{e_i\}_{i\in I}\subseteq M$ exists (as $R_1$ is nontrivial, the set $B$ is necessarily nonempty). Let $r = (0,1),$ and choose any $e\in B.$ Then we have
$$
er = e(0,1) = e\cdot 0 = 0,
$$
but $(0,1)\in R$ is not zero (as $R_2$ is not the trivial ring). This contradicts our assumption that $B$ was a basis. Therefore, assuming that both $R_1$ and $R_2$ are nontrivial, we have shown $R_1$ cannot be a free right $R_1\times R_2$-module via the natural action.